# Lógica de programação (Portugol) (VisualG). Como essa variável (MA) consegue me mostrar o nome exato do aluno que obteve a maior nota?

Tags: variáveis, visualg, portugol

O programa está funcionando perfeitamente. A minha dúvida é somente sobre esse algoritmo, não consigo entender como essa variável (MA) consegue me mostrar a maior nota apenas com a atribuição MA <- A. Se alguém conseguir me esclarecer essa questão eu agradeço.

```
Algoritmo "ContadorMaiorNota"

Var

   Q, contador: Inteiro

   N, MAIOR: Real

   A, MA: Caractere

Inicio

   contador <- 1

   Escreval("------------------------")

   Escreval(" ESCOLA ESTUDIOSOS ")

   Escreval("------------------------")

   Escreval("Quanto alunos tem na turma?")

   Leia(Q)

   Enquanto (contador <= Q) faca

      Escreval("Aluno ", contador)

      Escreval("Nome do aluno: ")

      Leia(A)

      Escreval("Nota do ", A,":")

      Leia(N)

      contador <- contador +1

      Se (N > MAIOR) entao

         MAIOR <- N

         MA <- A

      FimSe

   FimEnquanto

   Escreval("O maior aproveitamento foi o de ",MA," com a nota", MAIOR)

FimAlgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O algoritmo está lendo nomes e notas de vários alunos, e ao mesmo tempo que recebe essas informações, já calcula qual desses alunos teve a maior nota.

Então suponha que você vai inserir 3 alunas e suas respectivas notas:

Amanda, 9
Beatriz, 10
Carol, 8

No momento que eles passa por este bloco, o algoritmo está justamente fazendo o que propõe:

Se (N > MAIOR) entao
MAIOR <- N
MA <- A
FimSe

Onde N é a nota atual, MAIOR é a maior nota registrada até o momento (que inicialmente é zero), MA é “Maior Aluno” (o aluno que tirou a maior nota), e A é o nome do aluno atual.

Passo a passo, ele fez o seguinte:

1. Cadastrou Amanda, com nota 9. Como 9 é maior que o 0 inicial, entra naquela condição e define que até então a maior nota é 9 e a Maior Aluna é Amanda.
2. Cadastrou Beatriz, com nota 10. Como 10 é maior que 9, entra na condição e define que até o momento MAIOR nota é 10, e MA é Beatriz.
3. Cadastrou Carol, com nota 8. Como 8 é menor que 10, então ele não entrou na condição. Logo MAIOR nota e MA não foram alterados (continua Beatriz com nota 10).

Isso esclareceu que “MA <- A” é simplesmente guardar o nome da aluna atual, caso tenha entrado na condição de que a nota foi maior que a nota anterior?

Comment: Obrigada! Ajudou bastante na compreensão da condicional que eu não tinha me atentado antes.